# Creating a Survey in Play framework

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

i would like to create a Survey with different question types using Play! java. had someone an example source code to start with.

Comment: Here's a list of play examples: [Sample applications](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/Samples) . I think you can learn a great deal by adapting one of them to the survery you want to build.

Comment: oh thank you, i will try it